# Pandas create a new column containing index based on the value of another one

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
a


4.0
5.5
5.5
6.7
7.9
7.9
9.4
```

I want to a add a new column named `b`, 'indexing' the values in first one.
The new dataframe would look like:

```
a   b

4.0 1
5.5 2
5.5 2
6.7 3
7.9 4
7.9 4
9.4 5
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```py
codes, uniques = pd.factorize(df['a'])

df['b'] = codes
```

(or `df['b'] = codes + 1` if you want these indexes to start at 1 instead of 0)